# how to scrapy from a table with multi td nested tags

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have scrapy the data from this page (http://www.itjuzi.com/company/934), but what I want to get is a list with children td tags,and a list with parent td tags.

the code is below:

```
response.xpath("//table[@class='list-round-v2']//tr/td[4]//text()").extract()
```

and the result I want just like below:

```
[["骊悦投资","长山兴资本"],
["中信产业基金","高瓴资本Hillhouse Capital","IDG资本","北极光创投","DCM中国"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job

```
textlist=[]
for row in response.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'list-round-v2')]//tr"):
    textlist.append(row.xpath("td[4]//text()[parent::a|parent::span]").extract())
```